# Использование метода объекта в функции

Tags: javascript

Задача - необходимо использовать данные методы в функции. Методы `addYear()` и `show()`, соответственно, добавляют к текущей дате год и выводят ее на экран. Подход ниже позволяет использовать данные методы только с фиксированным значением (здесь - с текущей датой). Возможно применение методов подряд (чейнинг), как например: `plusYear.addYear().addYear().show()`.

```
var plusYear = {
  time: Date.now(),

  addYear: function() {
    this.time = this.time + 31557600000
    return this
  },

  show: function() {
    console.log(new Date(this.time))
    return this
   }
}
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы `time` можно было передавать как аргумент функции, то есть необходимо обернуть все эти методы в одну функцию (с сохранением возможности чейнинга). Считается, что в качестве аргумента всегда передается корректное значение в миллисекундах.

```
function plusYearAndShow(num) {
    var plusYear = {
    time: num,

    addYear: function() {
      this.time = this.time + 31557600000
      return this
    },

    show: function() {
      console.log(new Date(this.time))
      return this
    }
  }
}
```

Данный код не работает, буду благодарен за помощь в исправлении ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эмммм, почему бы просто не создать класс?

```js
class PlusYear {
  constructor(initialTime = Date.now()) {
    this.time = initialTime;
  }

  addYear() {
    this.time = this.time + 31557600000
    return this
  }

  show() {
    console.log(new Date(this.time))
    return this
  }
}

const plusYear = new PlusYear();
const plusYear2 = new PlusYear(+new Date('2017'));
plusYear.addYear().addYear().show();
plusYear2.addYear().addYear().show();
```

В вашем же случае, код не работает, потому что вы не возвращаете объект, поэтому и никакого `chaining` не возможно

Вариант с функцией:

```js
// просто возвращаем объект
const plusYearAndShow = num => ({
  time: num,

  addYear: function() {
    this.time = this.time + 31557600000
    return this
  },

  show: function() {
    console.log(new Date(this.time))
    return this
  }
});

const plusYear = plusYearAndShow(+ new Date('2017'));
plusYear.addYear().addYear().show();
```

Comment: я хотел бы реализовать это именно как функцию. Необходимо вернуть объект, то есть функция должна `return plusyear`?

Comment: @AlexLynch обновил ответ